# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named darkflow.cli and 'nms'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, yolo, darkflow

I am trying out YOLO tutorial at https://github.com/llSourcell/YOLO_Object_Detection

**When I do the step:**

```
flow --h
```

**I got this error:**

```
File "/anaconda2/bin/flow", line 4, in <module>
    from darkflow.cli import cliHandler
ImportError: No module named darkflow.cli
```

I have tried to find solution everywhere but no luck. Then I tried skip that line and continue...

```
flow --model cfg/yolo-new.cfg --load bin/yolo-tiny.weights --train --gpu 1.0
```

**I got this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flow", line 4, in <module>
    from darkflow.cli import cliHandler
  File "./YOLO_Object_Detection/darkflow/cli.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .net.build import TFNet
  File "./YOLO_Object_Detection/darkflow/net/build.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .framework import create_framework
  File "./YOLO_Object_Detection/darkflow/net/framework.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import yolo
  File "./YOLO_Object_Detection/darkflow/net/yolo/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import predict
  File "./YOLO_Object_Detection/darkflow/net/yolo/predict.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ...cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes import yolo_box_constructor
  File "darkflow/cython_utils/cy_yolo_findboxes.pyx", line 1, in init darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nms'
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both problems are discussed at the issue tracker.

> *ImportError: No module named darkflow.cli

https://github.com/llSourcell/YOLO_Object_Detection/issues/3

You have to build the cython modules:

```
cd ./cython_utils
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
cd ..
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nms'

https://github.com/llSourcell/YOLO_Object_Detection/issues/7

See https://keponk.wordpress.com/2017/12/07/siraj-darkflow/ for installation using `conda`.